# Como mostrar apenas linhas que aparecem mais de x vezes. (shell script)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script, log

Estou analisando um arquivo de log e eu queria filtrar apenas linhas que aparecem mais de 10 vezes dentro do arquivo. So que eu não estou conseguindo achar uma forma de fazer esse filtro.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você usará do seguinte comando:

```
sort SeuArquivo | uniq -c
```

Caso ainda deseje ordenar pela quantidade de ocorrências utilize:

```
sort SeuArquivo | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

Comment: +1 eventualmente `  ... | awk '$1 > 10 {print $2}`